# Is it acceptable to have multiple `set-cookie` headers in an HTTP/2 stream?

Tags: cookies, http2, setcookie

I'm proxying HTTP/2 client -> HTTP/1.1 server, and I'm not sure how to handle multiple `set-cookie` in the response.

I believe `set-cookie` is the only header which is allowed to be set multiple times for HTTP/1.1 - is this the case for HTTP/2 as well?

If I receive `set-cookie` multiple times in the HTTP/1.1 response, how do I send that back to the client over HTTP/2? Can I merge it together into a single header, or do I need to send multiple `set-cookie` headers back via HTTP/2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTTP/2 specification specifies how to handle cookies in [this section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.5).

It is the case for HTTP/2 as well that `set-cookie` is allowed to be set multiple times - its format would not allow otherwise.

A client receiving multiple `set-cookie` headers may send multiple `cookie` headers, or may concatenate them.

The server receiving multiple `cookie` headers must concatenate them
before invoking an application.